# Play Framework: how to find a local asset file based on the public URL?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

From an action class (Java), the way to translate a local asset path to a public path is

```
controllers.routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myscript.js");
```

However, I would like to translate a public absolute path (matching the current domain) to a local file. Something like (the non-existing):

```
File myLocalFile = controllers.routes.Aseets.local("http://www.mysite.com/assets/javascripts/myscript.js");
```

Of course, I could always parse the URL and hard-code the "public" -> "assets" mapping, but I'm looking for a hook in the router so that changes in the routes file don't affect my code.